# Setting innerHTML of HTML progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

I have a simple progress bar `<progress value="22" id = "timerProgress"></progress>`

I have managed to change its value using jQuery but I'd like to write text like `Remaining : 10 sec` INSIDE the progress bar.

I tried the innerHTML and the html properties but that didn't work out.

How to go about it?

Comment: The progress element can't have content like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the 'before' or 'after' CSS pseudo element (NB: at this time, this approach appears to work in Chrome only):

```
progress:before {
  content:attr(value);
}
```

Or create another attribute and update that from your JavaScript:

```
<progress value="22" id="timerProgress" data-content="Remaining : 10 sec"></progress>

progress:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}

var secondsRemaining = 10;
document.getElementById('timerProgress').setAttribute('data-content', 'Remaining : ' + secondsRemaining + ' sec');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imcg/v4xEB/

Comment: Now, how would I go about changing text color and all that?

Comment: Added a fiddle to the answer. Does work (in Chrome), but not 100% sure about browser support

Comment: That doesn't work in Safari or Firefox for me.  Does work in Chrome.  I don't have IE installed, so I can't check.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Yes you're right :before only seems to work in Chrome for the progress element. Going to add a warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to add another element.  I tried using a pseudo element on the progress bar, but for some reason it didn't work (only tried in Safari).

http://jsfiddle.net/smt6J/

HTML

```
<div id="progress">
    <progress max="100" value="22" class="progressBar"></progress>
    <div class="progressText">22% Done</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#progress .progressBar').val(50);
$('#progress .progressText').text('50% Done');
```

CSS

```
#progress {
    position:relative;
}
#progress .progressBar {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#progress .progressText {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks! :)

Will try it out.